# scrapy save item to mongodb : override duplicate data

Tags: python, mongodb, django-models, scrapy

I want to filter if there is already have the titleurl exist in mongo db
if yes,override to mongo db
Please guide me how to filter titleURL between scrapy and mongo?

items.py:

```
from scrapy.contrib.djangoitem import DjangoItem
from mongo_test.models import Ct
class CtItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = Ct
```

mongo_test/models.py:

```
class Ct(models.Model):   
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100)                 
    titleURL    = models.URLField(max_length=255)   
    .....
```

pipeline.py :

```
from mongo_test.models import Ct
class CtPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ct = item.save(commit=False)  
        ct_exist = Ct.objects.filter()  #how to let scrapy titleURL= mongo titleURL
    if ct_exist:
       # override to mongo
    ct.save()
    return item
```

settings.py in django project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
        'NAME': 'scrapy',
    } 
}
```

Comment: This `Citytalk` model - is it based on `MongoEngine`? Where is `mongodb` part here? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.I edit it. mongo_test is an APP in django project

Comment: @alecxc : I figure it out.I will delete the post after a while.Anyway.Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

**It will not save the duplicate data which is stored before by scraping script**

```
 try:
          find_data=list(mycol.find({
          "question":data['question'],
          "code_snippet":data['code_snippet']
          }))
          if len(find_data) == 0:
              mycol.insert_one(data)
 except: 
         find_data=list(mycol.find({"question":data['question']}))
           if len(find_data) == 0:
                 mycol.insert_one(data)
```